# Is there any way to run a python file without using the command line?

Tags: python

I need to run a python file, but I want to do it without using the command line. Is there any way to do this from the python shell or something?

Comment: Yes there is. Have you done any research whatsoever and/or found examples?

Comment: Launch it as a subprocess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, of course, use an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) that has a graphical "run" button.

Popular choices include:

- Pycharm
- IDLE
- Spyder
- PyDev
- Atom

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Python Shell

Use execfile for Python 2:

```
>>> execfile('C:\\test.py')
```

Use exec for Python 3

```
>>> exec(open("C:\\test.py").read())
```